# Ansible ad-hoc command background not working

Tags: ansible

It is my understanding that running ansible with -B will put the process in the background and I will get the console back. I don't know if I am using it wrong, or it is not working as expected. What I expect is to have the sleep command initiate on all three computers and then the prompt will be available to me to run another command. What happens is that I do not get access to the console until the command completes (in this case 2 minutes).

Is something wrong, am I misunderstanding what the `-B` does or am I doing it wrong?

With polling:
[image: with polling]

Without polling:
[image: without polling]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parameters to configure [async tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_async.html) in Ansible: `async` and `poll`.

`async` in playbooks (`-B` in ad-hoc) – total number of seconds you allow the task to run.
`poll` in playbooks (`-P` in ad-hoc) – period in seconds how often you want check for result.

So if you just need *fire and forget* ad-hoc command, use `-B 3600 -P 0`: allow 1 min execution and don't care about result.
By default `-P 15`, so `ansible` doesn't exit but checks your job every 15 seconds.